# combinig two observables with rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I have an app where user can invoke 2 actions:

- get list of items
- add item

For both actions, view should display current items.
Is there any elegant way to do it with rxjs operators?

Current implementation:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();
    }

addItem = () => {
    this.addedItem$ = this.httpClient.post(url,
      { name: 'foo'}
    ).subscribe(() => {
        this.getItems();
      });
  }

 private getItems() {
    this.items$ = this.httpClient.get(url);
  }
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
```

I dont want to fetch list of all items every time new items is added.
Would be better if I could combine two streams together.

Comment: So if i understood right, you want to load list of items, also you want to have some kind of form (or whatever in the same view) that will add new item to the list and also make 'post' request to the server. Also you dont want to make new get request each time that you are adding a new item?  If i had understood corectly, i want to ask you do you have the power to change the server response of the `post` request?

Comment: I can change POST response

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using observable object you can store fetched items in plain js array. After adding new item you can just push new item to this array.

```
items = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getItems();
}

addItem = () => {
  const item = { name: 'foo'};
  this.httpClient.post(url, item)
      .subscribe(() => this.items.push(item));
}

private getItems() {
  this.httpClient.get(url)
      .subscribe(items => this.items = items)
}


<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

edit: or use `BehaviorSubject`

```
  items = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();
  }

  addItem = () => {
    const item = { name: 'foo'};
     this.httpClient.post(url, item)
        .subscribe(() => this.items.next([...this.items.value, item]));
  }

  private getItems() {
    this.httpClient.get(url)
        .subscribe(items => this.items.next(items))
  }

  <div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to use observables for that

Comment: edited my answer, you can achieve that using `BehaviorSubject` which is a subtype of observable